# Cannot allocate iOS MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, sendmail

I downloaded a sample  project that use `MFMailComposeViewController`, The requirement is framework MessageUI, and setup the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`.

But when step through the code

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

The `mailController` didn't get a valid address 0x0, meaning it's not memory allocated. I don't know it can't be allocated. I checked the sample code and it's correctly allocated.

What's the difference?  Why it can't allocated?

Answer (score 5):

Jason,

You probably don't have any mail account configured on the device/simulator. You probably should first check if the device can send mail using

```
+ (BOOL)canSendMail
```

method of [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

The general approach in the MessageUI framework is that a nil object is returned on creation if no account is configured.